# Build a Dict of Counts based on Two Dataframe Columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
    start   stop
0   1       2
1   3       4
2   2       1
3   4       3
```

I'm trying to build a dictionary with key= (start, stop) pairs from my list of tuples and the value= count of their occurrence, regardless of the order. In other words, (1,2) and (2,1) would both count as an occurrence of the pair (1,2) in the list of tuples.

Desired output: `dict_count= {('1','2'):2, ('3','4'):2}`

Here's my attempt:

`my_list=[('1','2'),('3','4')]`

```
for pair in my_list:
    count=0
    if ((df[df['start']]==pair[0] and df[df['end']]==pair[1]) or (df[df['start']]==pair[1]) and df[df['end']]==pair[0])::
        count+=1
    dict_count[pair]=count
```

However, this gives me a KeyError:
`KeyError: "['1' ...] not in index"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `values` + `sort` then we do `groupby`

```
df.values.sort()
df
  start stop
0   '1'  '2'
1   '3'  '4'
2   '1'  '2'
3   '3'  '4'
df.groupby(df.columns.tolist()).size()
start  stop
'1'    '2'     2
'3'    '4'     2
dtype: int64
```

If you need `dict`

```
df.groupby(df.columns.tolist()).size().to_dict()
{("'1'", "'2'"): 2, ("'3'", "'4'"): 2}
```

Update

```
df['orther']=1
df[['start','stop']]=np.sort(df[['start','stop']].values)
df.groupby(['start','stop']).size().to_dict()
{("'1'", "'2'"): 2, ("'3'", "'4'"): 2}
```

Comment: Thank you; my df has a lot of other columns. Would `df.values.sort()` preserve the order in the other columns?

Comment: @Caerus btw if it is work for you , do not forget upvote and accept :-)

Comment: Found an alt :)

Answer (score 6):

Use `collections.Counter`:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter(map(tuple, np.sort(df[['start','stop']], axis=1)))
{(1, 2): 2, (3, 4): 2}
```

This does not modify your original DataFrame.